# Is there a way to mirror a mesh with hair but without deforming these?

Tags: particles, transforms, hair

i was trying to mirror some eyelids with some hair but they don't seem to appear on the mirror version of the eyelid, so, i decided to apply the mirror but then the hair deforms like this:

[image]

Maybe i'm still too noob, but i don't see a way of how to fix the deformed hairs on the other eyelid. 
Also, i tried to duplicate and deform the mesh with mirror transform, but isn't the same like the mirror modifier, but unlike the mirror modifier, the hairs doesn't seem to get deformed. Still, it's not a good way to do it:
[image]
You can clearly see that the hairs remained good but the mirror modification fails on his mission (or maybe the one who's failing is me :P)

So, is there a way to mirror an object without the mirror modifier but with the same results as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Edit Mode*, flip normals on the mirrored parts, then go to *Particle Mode*, enable *X-Mirroring*, set *Comb Tool* strength to 0.001 and comb the original side, the mirrored sidewill match.

If there are any artifacts with some of the hair you can fix them manually or delete/recreate individual guides with mirror on.